# How to count number of unique words in C

Tags: c

I need to count number of each unique words that user have entered from the keyboard. Should I use `scanf` or `fgets` to store sentence.

I have tried using `fgets` and compiler throw an error.

Comment: To count the number of unique words, no words need to be saved.  Jack Empire, do words need to be saved in addition to counting them?

Comment: @Reinstate how can you say whether the 3rd word is a dupe without storing the 1st one?

Comment: "I have tried using fgets and compiler throw an error" means that your usage was incorrect. If you want to know how to use `fgets`, ask a question like "I tried to use `fgets` like this [complete example goes here] but I got this compiler error [complete error message text goes here]." That's a question which can  probably be answered, and it's quite possible that you'll learn something useful from the answer. "I tried X but I couldn't get it right so what should I try next?" is not a question which anyone will bother answering. And even if they did, you still won't know how to use `fgets`.

Comment: Also, compiler error messages do usually give you some kind of idea about what was wrong. You should at least try to understand what the message is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` it's the best way to read a sentence, if you choose this path then you need to use `strtok` to extrapolate the single words from the sentence.

I suggest you to use `fgets`, `strtok` and  `strstr`. I guess that's the best way.

`strtok` and `strstr` are defined in the `strimg.h` header.

Comment: `strtok()` is bad advice. In general do not use `strtok()` because of `static` variables.

Answer (score -1):

You can prefer `scanf` to store a sentence in a variable on your `C` program. With the below code you can store 50 charachters.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    char a[50];
    printf("Read a string:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", a);
    printf("\nThe Sentence is; %s", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s", a);` you don't need the `s`

Comment: Fyi, `fflush(stdin);` invokes *undefined behavior*. `fflush` is exclusively for file streams opened for *wriitng*, which `stdin` is *not*. Whatever text told you to do this.. burn it.

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]", a);`  is worse than `gets()`.  It does not even read a whole line (leaving the `'\n'`) in `stdin` and is quite useless if the line begins with `'\n'`.